# If array values (taken from a NetSuite field) are empty, remove from array?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, netsuite

Trying to put together an API integration using netsuite/celigo and a 3rd party marketplace. most of the JSON has been fine but having trouble getting the photos to work. they have to be passed as an array, but each of our items has a different number of photos. I have access to SQL expressions in netsuite and a sort of "JSON document builder" with several functions built in as well inside of Celigo.

this is what the information being passed looks like (i replaced the actual url with a fake one). So I need a way to remove those blank fields from the array, which show up currently as "",

```
  "photos": ["url.jpg", "url2.jpg", "", "", ],
```

The "document builder" side looks like this (it seems like Celigo's syntax), again lots of functions available too but not in use and not sure which to use.

```
 "photos":["{{this.0.Photo1}}", "{{this.0.Photo2}}", "{{this.0.Photo3}}", "{{this.0.Photo4}}",],
```

(where the netsuite fields for photos 3 and are empty)

I tried just concatenating all the urls, but then they won't be in the proper array format and the same issue still applies of the extra characters where the fields are blank. I have to avoid changing how the data is actually entered into the NS field as this would screw up our other integrations.

Answer (score 1):

considering you have this: `"photos": ["url.jpg", "url2.jpg", "", "", ],`

that processed by Celigo yields this: `"photos":["{{this.0.Photo1}}", "{{this.0.Photo2}}", "{{this.0.Photo3}}", "{{this.0.Photo4}}",],`

How about you use **Array.filter()**?

```
let ob = {
 //..other properties
 photos:  ["url.jpg", "url2.jpg", "", "", ]
}
ob.photos = ob.photos.filter(function(el) { return el });
```

**EDIT**
following  erictgrubaugh's comment, seems like Netsuite runs Ecmascript 5, so lamnda will not work. I have changed it to the previous JS version

Comment: Be aware that this specific syntax will not work in server-side NetSuite as it does not support ES6+. `Array.filter()` will certainly work well for this case though. See examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Examples